# how to keep heroku User records when you need to restart the schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku, devise

So I'm in a small pickle.

Early out this week my manager told me to try to fix the a mailing problem that we were having in our app.

Now the app had no reason to fail in mailer, so what I tried to do I recreated a whole new project of the rails app while following the steps of the old one. 
Which went great I got the mailer back on working.

Now the problem is I need to deploy it to heroku.... AOWWW

I used a whole new schema of the database in developing the other app. And I fear if I go and deploy we will loose the old User records, so as the Users Posts.

The User Posts though are easier to recreate since I can add them manually to the DB but I m having a problem with the User fields.

Since the User fields having an encrypted password using devise auth I wonder if I change the new app secret key by the old one will that make it work?

What different approach can I take to solve this problem.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: do you know unencrypted password in user table

Comment: No I only have access to the encrypted passwords

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes if you changed the new app secret key by the old one it will work

```
OR
```

if you know plain text password run in console

```
User.create(password: "yourpassword", password_confirmation: "yourpassword")
```

Comment: Alright great, I don't know the plain password. Question as well  you think it will be a gd idea to decrypt the passwords then readd them rather then changin gthe app secret

Comment: no you can not decrypt it, but for now you can replace encrypted_password of your old_app in your new project.